What's the correct tanslation of "The Immaculate Conception of the Blessed Virgin Mary"?
This is for a piece of artwork.
I used an online translator that came up with "Conceptio Immaculata B. Mariae V.", but I do not know if this is correct. I just thought the initialized abbreviations looked strange.
Any help would be appreciated!
Thanks!

It is correct, but abbreviated (B for Beatae, V for Virginis). In full (and in the usual word order): Immaculata Conceptio Beatae (or Beatissimae = most blessed) Virginis Mariae. Capitalize to taste.

Thank you! What did you mean by "the usual word order"? Is there another way of saying it?

I encounter the order Beata Maria Virgo much more commonly than Beata Virgo Maria in Latin. This is the opposite of the usual English usage.
